# Duplicate content due to multiple categories per product

Tags: seo, canonical

On my website, there is a category `special offers`. The way I fill this category is by just assigning the product to both, the standard category and the `special offers` one. Of course this leads to duplicate content for Google.

The question: Which is the best way of avoiding duplicate content for articles which are assigned to more than one category, for example by canonicalizing the `special offers` category? Is there a feature for it? Do I need to build this myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento has the inbuild functionlity of Canonical.Just go to `System > Configuration > Catalog > Search Engine Optimizations`.their Select Yes for  `Use Canonical Link Meta Tag For Categories` and  `Use Canonical Link Meta Tag For Products` and save and clear the cache.

Comment: I don't think this is the solution. both categories will have own canonical urls but same product(s). Google will still consider this duplicate content.

Comment: @murtzagondal I agree to you as I am facing the issue you mentioned, is there any solution to handle this?